# Need help with validating a date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have the code below and it works pretty good except if you enter something like 2/2/2011, you get the error message "The Document Date is not a valid date". I would expect that it would say "The Document Date needs to be in the format MM/DD/YYYY".

Why does the line `newDate = dateFormat.parse(date);` not catch that?

```
// checks to see if the document date entered is valid
    private String isValidDate(String date) {

        // set the date format as mm/dd/yyyy
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        Date newDate = null;

        // make sure the date is in the correct format..        
        if(!date.equals("mm/dd/yyyy")) {
            try {
                newDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            } catch(ParseException e) {
                return "The Document Date needs to be in the format MM/DD/YYYY\n";
            }

            // make sure the date is a valid date..
            if(!dateFormat.format(newDate).toUpperCase().equals(date.toUpperCase())) {
                return "The Document Date is not a valid date\n";
            }

            return "true";
        } else {
            return "- Document Date\n";
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** I'm trying to enforce strict adherence to the format MM/DD/YYYY. How can I change the code so that if a user enters "2/2/2011", it will display the message: "The Document Date needs to be in the format MM/DD/YYYY"?

Comment: Alot of this code doesn't do anything useful.  Can provide a simpler example of your code as I would just be tempted to remove most of it.

Comment: `2` is a valid year so I wouldn't expect it to produce an error and I would expect it to format to `02/02/0002` which is not the same as `2/2/2`  Even 6/1/2011 will fail your test.

Comment: It was supposed to be 2/2/2011. I've updated it.

Comment: That will be formatted as `02/02/2011` as you specified so it won't match.

Comment: No it won't. It gives the message "The Document Date is not a valid date". I would expect it to give the message "The document date needs to be in the format MM/DD/YYYY".

Comment: But it parses just fine, it just doesn't produce the same format()

Comment: Not sure i'm following you. With the code I posted, if you put "2/2/2011", it gives the error "The Document Date is not a valid date". I want it to display the other message. If you put in "02/02/2011". it works just fine as I would expect.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic about the format, you need to use the approach of checking the format() matches the original string as you have done. BTW, there is no point of using Uppercase, if you really need it you can use equalsCaseIgnore()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned, the `SimpleDateFormat` is able to parse "2/2/2011" as if it is "02/02/2011". so no `ParseException` is thrown.

On the other hand, `dateFormat.format(newDate)` will return "02/02/2011" and is compared against "2/2/2011". The two strings aren't equal, so the second error message is returned.

`setLenient(false)` will not work in this case:

> Month: If the number of pattern letters is 3 or more, the month is interpreted as text; *otherwise, it is interpreted as a **number**.*
>
> Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. *For **parsing**, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.*

(source: [java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#number))

you can use a regular expression to manually check the string format:

```
if(date.matches("[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}")) {
    // parse the date
} else {
    // error: wrong format
}
```

Comment: That worked. I must not have understood what parsing the date actually did. I thought that it validated that it was in the correct format.

Comment: Unfortunately for you not. The parser is actually pretty smart and recognizes the weirdest strings. i just successfully parsed the string "0211111/0211111/2011111111" (with lenient parsing, with strict parsing a ParseException is thrown). That is good for making the best out of malformed user input, but very bad in your case.

Comment: +1. It would be nice if the `SimpleDateFormat` docs would have clarified the lenient behavior on `SimpleDateFormat#parse()` method itself, since it essentially supersedes (and maybe even violates the contract with) the documentation for `DateFormat#parse()`. That is, unless my interpretation of "strict" (as documented by `DateFormat#parse()`) is wrong.

Comment: i too assumed that strict parsing is... well... strict. seems like in this context "strict" means "a bit less lenient than lenient". I wasn't able to find a definition of what exactly the difference of lenient and strict parsing is, just examples like [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Leniency.htm), and i gave up trying to figure it out by experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

The date is correct, but it will be formatted as 02/02/2002

Comment: I know it is, that's what the issue is. I would expect the the error message to display what the format should be, not that it is an invalid date.

Comment: if i remember correctly, the date is even 2nd february in the year 2 A.D., isn't it?

Comment: @Catfish: then you have to check the string with a regex. if the SimpleDateFormat is able to parse the string, it simply does it without throwing an exception.

Comment: Well it's the error message that YOU returns, not the one throw in an exception (no exception is thrown)